# promise not checking value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i am trying to check the field value using promise but in the promise function it seem it was unable to check the email input value. and it will give blank result?

```
<form>
<label for="Email">Email</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="Form_email">
<div id="Email_error"></div>
</form>
```

```
$(function() {
  let Email = $("#Form_email");
  let Email_valid_field = $("#Email_error");


  //promise
 let myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 setTimeout(function() {
  if (Email.val() === "abc@yahoo.com") {
    reject();
    console.log("reject");
  } else {
    resolve();
  }
}, 250);

  });
 Email.focus(function() {}).blur(function() {
   myFirstPromise
  .then(
    result => {
      Email_valid_field.append("<p>Email Available</p>");
    },
    reject => {
      Email_valid_field.append("<p>Email Is Taken</p>");
    }
  )
  .catch(() => {});
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code: `myFirstPromise` is a Promise and it only runs once. So if you check after it has been solved (you can `console.log(myFirstPromise)`).

You have to wrap it in a function like this:

```
$(function () {
    let Email_valid_field = $("#Email_error");
    let Email = $("#Form_email");
    //promise
    function checkValidEmail() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(function () {
                let Email = $("#Form_email");

                if (Email.val() === "abc@yahoo.com") {
                    reject();
                    console.log("reject");
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            }, 250);

        });
    }

    Email.focus(function () {
    }).blur(function () {
        checkValidEmail()
            .then(
                result => {
                    Email_valid_field.append("<p>Email Available</p>");
                },
                reject => {
                    Email_valid_field.append("<p>Email Is Taken</p>");
                }
            )
            .catch(() => {
            });
    });
});
```

And after each check, function `checkValidEmail` always return a new **Promise** and you can recheck value of email input.

Comment: the problem is the email.val() did not output value ,it will return no value https://jsfiddle.net/123Adca/bpv1yw0g/1/ , it will always resolve